# Meaning of "I consider one as including the other."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “When I talked of your being altered by time, by the progress of years,” said John Knightley, “I meant to imply the change of situation which time usually brings. **I consider one as including the other**. Time will generally lessen the interest of every attachment not within the daily circle—but that is not the change I had in view for you. As an old friend, you will allow me to hope, Miss Fairfax, that ten years hence you may have as many concentrated objects as I
> have.”

> Emma by Jane Austen
> chapter 16 volume 2

In the bold part I'm confused about what is the "one" and the "other". Is he saying the passage of time includes the change of the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Knightley has been suggesting that Jane Fairfax will be less eager for letters when she is older. He explains that he means that her circumstances will probably have changed (that is, she will be married with a family, and less interested in people outside the family circle). So, yes, he means that the passage of time implies changes of situation.

(It's Chapter 34 in a modern one-volume edition, but I  managed to track down the passage using Google Books!)